# Blender Cycles shows object in viewport render but not in final render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects

I'm following a really great forest tutorial.

This is a picture of my render in the viewport. In the bottom left and right corners you can make out a little dirt texture that I've added onto the ground.

[image]

Here is the image in the final render.
[image]

In the bottom left and right corners you can see a transparency texture which means that Cycles is not rendering my ground object. The object is enabled for rendering in the outliner.

[image]

It is also checked for "show in renders" in the object properties panel

[image]

As always, help is greatly appreciated and thank you for reading my post.

Here is the blend file.

[image]

Comment: Please pack your textures into your .blend file using File ▸ External Data ▸ Pack All Into .blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DirtGround object does not have the *Show Emitter* checkbox checked under the particle system render settings, only under the viewport settings:

[image]

If you check that checkbox, your ground object should appear in renders as well.